# The "Tab Name" for Deleted Spam Questions still shows the Original Text

Tags: bug, spam, window-title

For questions deleted as spam or R/A, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72616287/10871073), the question title (header) is replaced by the "System" with the following text:

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore
> not shown.

However, the name in the browser tab 'title' is still showing the original text (and hovering over that tab shows the *full* text).

Screenshot for those without the 10k (view deleted posts) privilege:

[image: window title with spam]

From a [recent discussion in the SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54750246#54750246), this behaviour appears to be the same in multiple browsers.

If the purpose of replacing the original text is to hide it from 'casual' viewers (it can always be found, anyway, by viewing the post's revision history), then shouldn't the page title (presumably, in its `<title>` tag) also be replaced, so that that text isn't displayed by default in the tab name? Or would doing so have undesired consequences in terms of the post's history?